# Using labels with diagrams in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, diagram

I'm trying to display point data as diagrams with labes next them. I'm getting the diagrams and labels to work separately, but they won't work together. When both are turned on, the labels disappear and as soon as I turn off the diagrams, the labels reappear.

Does anyone know how to show them together?

Comment: @Joseph, it does! Although now the labels are overlapping eachother, but I guess I should be able to find a solution for that. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked :). Yes, you may need to play around with the `Rendering` settings of the labels and `Placement` settings for labels and diagrams. Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can show both diagrams and labels at the same time by enabling:

`Labels > Rendering > Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)`

If labels and/or diagrams overlap, you may need to adjust the `Rendering` and `Placement` settings.